# How to add event handlers to a dynamically created textbox control from server side code in asp.net

Tags: c#

I have a gridview control wherein I have added textbox in coloumn 5 & 6 dynamically from server side code as below:

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txtFrom = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox();
            txtFrom.ID = "txtFrom";
            txtFrom.Width = 70;
            txtFrom.AutoPostBack = true;
            txtFrom.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.txtFrom_Changed);
            e.Row.Cells[5].Controls.Add(txtFrom);

            System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txtTo = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox();
            txtTo.ID = "txtTo";
            txtTo.Width = 70;
            txtTo.AutoPostBack = true;
            txtTo.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.txtTo_Changed);
            e.Row.Cells[6].Controls.Add(txtTo);
        }
    }
```

However when I am calling the Textchanged event (code shown below), the textboxes are disappearing.

```
protected void txtTo_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox textbox = (sender as System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox);
        MyAlert(textbox.ID + " text changed value: " + textbox.Text);
    }
```

Request you to suggest why this is happening and how can I solve this.

Thanking you all in anticipation.

Comment: As a result of your server request the server will build your page again and during that action it is not triggering OnRowDataBound. You should debug and put a breakpoint in OnRowDataBound to confirm that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I could solve the issue by modifying the code as below and calling the new function during postback.

```
protected void getDateControls()
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow grow in gdView.Rows)
        {
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txtFrom = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox();
            txtFrom.ID = "txtFrom";
            txtFrom.Width = 70;
            txtFrom.AutoPostBack = true;
            txtFrom.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.txtFrom_Changed);
            grow.Cells[5].Controls.Add(txtFrom);

            System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txtTo = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox();
            txtTo.ID = "txtTo";
            txtTo.Width = 70;
            txtTo.AutoPostBack = true;
            txtTo.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.txtTo_Changed);
            grow.Cells[6].Controls.Add(txtTo);
        }
    }
```